# LaTeX code output by Calc wrong

Tags: latex, auctex, calc

If I enable calc-embedded mode (C-x * e) in a LaTeX document (latex mode by default) when the point is in the math environment of the document below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\evalto}{}
\renewcommand*{\to}{=}
\begin{math}
[[ a, b ][ c, d ]] * [[x][y]]   =>
\end{math}
\end{document}
```

calc embedded produces the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\evalto}{}
\renewcommand*{\to}{=}
\begin{math}
\evalto \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix} a x + b y \\ c x + d y \end{pmatrix}
\end{math}
\end{document}
```

which perfectly render the desired output.

[image: Produit matriciel]

But this is not the case if I want to activate the latex 2 display mode to have a prettier source code:

```
% [calc mode: language: (latex 2)]
\begin{math}
\evalto \begin{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix}
        a & b \\               x \\                a x + b y \\ 
        c & d                  y                   c x + d y
        \end{pmatrix}          \end{pmatrix}       \end{pmatrix}
\end{math}
```

Which does not render the desired output.
So I have to move rectangular data to get it.

Is there a way to get the correct output in an easy way?

Answer (score 1):

This is documented behaviour. From section 7.8.3 of the Calc manual:

> If you invoke
> ‘d T’ or ‘d L’ with an argument of 2 or −2, then matrices will be
> displayed in two-dimensional form, such as

```
 \begin{pmatrix}
 a & b \\
 c & d
 \end{pmatrix}
```

> This may be convenient for isolated matrices, but could lead to
> expressions being displayed like

```
 \begin{pmatrix} \times x
 a & b \\
 c & d
 \end{pmatrix}
```

> While this wouldn’t bother Calc, it is incorrect LaTeX.  (Similarly for
> TeX.)

Comment: That's exactly what I complained about. Probably I expressed myself badly. English is not my mother tongue.  I am looking for a solution to avoid having to edit the code produced by Calc.

Comment: I think the point is that latex 2 is inappropriate for yr use-case.  Source code is not prettier if it is incorrect ;-)

Comment: I know that. My example is a 2x2 matrix, but what about a much larger matrix? I have some tricks to get around this difficulty, for example moving the code around with copying rectangles. But it's a bit boring. Probably I can compose some macro.